# Am I running a 32-bit or 64 bit Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

When I run `select @@version` I get the following: I think Intel X86 means i am running the 32 bit version - but then I also see the X64 at the end....

> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2) - 10.50.4000.0 (Intel X86) Jun 28 2012 08:42:37
>   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition with Advanced Services on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (WOW64)

When I run `Exec master.dbo.xp_msver` I get the following:

```
1   ProductName NULL    Microsoft SQL Server
2   ProductVersion  655410  10.50.4000.0
3   Language    1033    English (United States)
4   Platform    NULL    NT INTEL X86
5   Comments    NULL    SQL
6   CompanyName NULL    Microsoft Corporation
7   FileDescription NULL    SQL Server Windows NT
8   FileVersion NULL    2009.0100.4000.00 ((KJ_PCU_Main).120628-0827 )
9   InternalName    NULL    SQLSERVR
10  LegalCopyright  NULL    Microsoft Corp. All rights reserved.
11  LegalTrademarks NULL    Microsoft SQL Server is a registered trademark of Microsoft Corporation.
12  OriginalFilename    NULL    SQLSERVR.EXE
13  PrivateBuild    NULL    NULL
14  SpecialBuild    262144000   NULL
15  WindowsVersion  498139398   6.1 (7601)
16  ProcessorCount  4   4
17  ProcessorActiveMask 15  0000000f
18  ProcessorType   586 PROCESSOR_INTEL_PENTIUM
19  PhysicalMemory  8073    8073 (8465080320)
20  Product ID  NULL    NULL
```

Comment: WOW64 means that windows 64 bit, but sql server is 32

Comment: You are running a 32-bit application (SQL Server 2008 R2) on a 64-bit operating system. Such a thing is made possible by **W**indows 32-bit **O**n **W**indows 64-bit (aka [WOW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WoW64) ) technology by Microsoft. That's why you see that WOW64 string in the end of the text describing your operating system in the query output.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm getting:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3128.0 (X64)
```

So yes - `X86` means 32-bit, and in my case, `X64` stands for 64 bit

and `exec master.dbo.xp_msver` returns:

```
4   Platform    NULL    NT x64
```

Again - `x64` = 64-bit, while yours says `X86` = 32-bit

Answer (score 2):

This: `Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2) - 10.50.4000.0 (Intel X86)` means you're running the 32-bit (X86) version.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT @@VERSION
```

would also give you the datapath width (32 or 64 bit):

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2500.0 (X64) 
    Jun 17 2011 00:54:03 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 **<X64>** (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)
```